# Append element to smallest list in dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists for which I want to add a value to a particular list...

```
d = {'a': [4, 2], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': [4, 3], 'd': [4, 3], 'e': [4], 'f': [4], 'g': [4]}
```

I want to add the number 2 to the just one of the lists with the smallest length.

```
def gsl(x):
    return [k for k in x.keys() if len(x.get(k))==min([len(n) for n in x.values()])]
```

after calling

```
>>> gsl(d)
['e', 'g', 'f']
```

So in this case, I want to append the number 2 to the list `'e'` in the dictionary making it `[4,2]` (order doesnt matter.

Result should be

```
>>> d['e']
[4,2]
```

I've tried

```
for i in d:
    if gsl(d)[0] == i: #gets the first key with the smallest value 
        d[i].append(2) # if equal, adds 2 to the dictionary value that matches
```

Except that adds `2` to each `'e'`, `'g'`, `'f'`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try killing the for loop and see if that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> d = {'a': [4, 2], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': [4, 3], 'd': [4, 3], 'e': [4], 'f': [4], 'g': [4]}
>>> smallest = min(d, key=lambda k: len(d[k]))
>>> d[smallest].append(2)
>>> d
{'a': [4, 2], 'c': [4, 3], 'b': [3, 4], 'e': [4, 2], 'd': [4, 3], 'g': [4], 'f': [4]}
```

Comment: What if I wanted to get the second smallest list? So not the smallest one, but the one that is right after

Comment: @user1530318 `heapq` will do that for you :) `>>> from heapq import nsmallest`
`>>> nsmallest(2, d, key=lambda k: len(d[k]))[-1]`
`'g'`

Comment: Sweet, that works! So now that returns me the next smallest number. If I wanted to do something like hey find the smallest list and if it has a particular word it in, let's say "john" then only can you append this number. Otherwise, find the next smallest list till that happens. The best way to do this using the heapq would probably be through a recursive function right?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
d[gsl(d)[0]].append(2)
```

`gsl(d)` gets the list of keys with minimal length, `0` gets the first one, and then we get the list at that key and append `2` to it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your answer is that, after inserting the element in 'e', it is not anymore part of the "keys with minimum length lists", so on the next iteration it will return ['f', 'g'].

One quick fix to it is to break the loop, like this:

```
for i in d:
    if gsl(d)[0] == i:
        d[i].append(2)
        break
```

But this is a very inefficient way of doing what you want, and will fail if d is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python 2.7 or newer, you can use a [view](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) for this:

```
>>> d = {'a': [4, 2], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': [4, 3], 'd': [4, 3], 'e': [4], 'f': [4], 'g': [4]}
>>> min(d.viewitems(), key=lambda (k, v): len(v))[1].append(2)
>>> d
{'a': [4, 2], 'c': [4, 3], 'b': [3, 4], 'e': [4, 2], 'd': [4, 3], 'g': [4], 'f': [4]}
```

If you're using an older version, you can use [iteritems](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems):

```
>>> d = {'a': [4, 2], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': [4, 3], 'd': [4, 3], 'e': [4], 'f': [4], 'g': [4]}
>>> min(d.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v): len(v))[1].append(2)
>>> d
{'a': [4, 2], 'c': [4, 3], 'b': [3, 4], 'e': [4, 2], 'd': [4, 3], 'g': [4], 'f': [4]}
```

Comment: Actually `dict.viewitems` is only python 2.7. In python 3 it is the default behaviour for the `dict.items` method.  Your second approach is what I used originally but I thought my current solution looked nicer :) Also I recently found out that tuple unpacking in functions (`lambda (k, v)`) is removed in Python 3 so I decided to stop using it from now on.