# How to append an element to list that is in dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I reviewed those posts: [append list inside dictionary with update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119860/append-list-inside-dictionary-with-update?answertab=oldest#tab-top) and [Append element to smallest list in dictionary of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731534/append-element-to-smallest-list-in-dictionary-of-lists).
They didn't help help me. I wanted to do something like that: there was a `result = {}` and `spl = input().split(' ')`, I did *something* and it turned into `result = {'text': [1, 2]}` (for example). How to do this?

I tried to make a thing like in the first link: `result.update({'text': result['text'] + [1, 2]})`, but it did not worked. I also tried thing from the second link:

```py
result = {'text': []}
result['text'].append(1, 2)
```

but it gave me an error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`. The real code part until the intended part is down below.

The code:

```py
def checkThru(txt, wordsDesc=1, countMoreMost=False, indexInOutput=False):
    result = {}
    spl = txt.split(' ')
    badChars = ['?', ',', '.', '!',]
    wordam = list(range(0, wordsDesc))

    for lol in range(len(spl)):
        for sublol in badChars:
             spl[lol] = spl[lol].replace(sublol, "")

    for i in spl:

        iinspl = spl.index(i)

        if indexInOutput == True:

            if i == 'are' or i == 'am' or i == 'is' or i == 'were' or i == \
            'was' or i == 'will' or i == 'shall':

                if spl[iinspl + 1] == 'a' or spl[iinspl + 1] == 'an' or \
                spl[iinspl + 1] == 'the':

                    if countMoreMost == False:

                        if spl[iinspl + 2] == 'more' or spl[iinspl + 2] == 'most':

                            result.update({iinspl-1: []})

                            for add in wordam:

                                result.update({spl[iinspl-1].append(iinspl+3+add)}) #???(Here's where the error says something is wrong.)
#Actually, spl[iinspl-1] is going to be a list, because of the line <<result.update({iinspl-1: []})>>
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\I MADE A MODULE!!! indeX.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(indeX.checkThru('Hello, I am David. My sister is the most Ann babe', 1, False, True))
  File "C:\Users\Danil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\indeX.py", line 287, in checkThru
    result.update({spl[iinspl-1].append(iinspl+1+add)})
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I wanted it to make a dictionary of characteristics. For example:

```py
print(checkThru('Hi, I am David, and my sister is Ann!'))

>>> {'I': ['David'], 'sister': ['Ann']}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could make your question smaller. And please add the traceback. Which lines causes the AttributeError?

Comment: Running your code: `result['text'].append(1, 2)` gives me `TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`, not the `AttributeError` you posted.

Comment: `.append(1, 2)` was just an example

Comment: Accurate examples will help _a lot_ more with answering your question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The second-link thing you posted:

```py
result = {'text': []}
result['text'].append(1, 2)
```

...will work. The error you're getting is because of what it says - you're trying to run append on a string.

Your `spl` list is a list of strings, resulting from `txt.split()`. Your code:

```py
spl[iinspl-1].append()
```

...will therefore always be trying to append to a string, which (as you're finding) doesn't work.

I think probably in that bit of code you mean to be appending to `result`, not `spl`?

EDIT: Or else you want something like:

```py
result[spl[iinspl-1]].append(iinspl+3+add))
```

Might be update rather than append, depending on exactly what's in there and what you want out.

Comment: When I use `result[spl[iinspl-1]].update({iinspl-1: [iinspl+1+add]})` with `print(indeX.checkThru('Hello, I am David. My sister is the most Ann babe', 1, False, True))` it outputs: `KeyError: 'I'`, because `spl[iinspl-1]` = `'I'` but I will try earlier thing you said.

Comment: I tried to do this: `result.update({spl[iinspl-1]: [iinspl+2+add]})` but it didn't worked((( For some reason it outputs: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
result = {'text': []}
result['text'].append(1, 2)
```

Shouldn't give `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'` unless you define the value of `result['text']` as a string before trying to append.

However, `append` doesn't take two arguments like that. If you want to add `1` and `2` to the list, you would do one of:

```
result = {'text': []}
result['text'].append(1)
result['text'].append(2)

print(result)
```

prints:

```
{'text': [1, 2]}
```

or

```
result = {'text': []}
result['text'] += [1, 2]

print(result)
```

prints:

```
{'text': [1, 2]}
```

Comment: When I do this: `result[iinspl-1] += spl(iinspl+1+add)`, it outputs: `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: it looks like `spl` is a list based on the error. So you can't call it like `spl(args)`.

Answer (score 0):

`result = {'text': []}
result['text'].append(1, 2)`

Will give

> TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
>   because append takes only one argument. Not the one you have mentioned.

One way to go is append element by element if you dont want to return a list of list.
`result = {'text':[]}
result['text'].append(1)
result['text'].append(2)
result
{'text': [1, 2]}` will give the desired result

Or use `update` instead. The syntax seems fine:

`result.update({'text': [1, 2]})
result
{'text': [1, 2]}`

Having said that, 
After a quick review of the code:

1. All the decisions are triggered via if conditions (only if-nested blocks) so all should be `True` such that your `result` dictionary gets modified please review that once.
2. Default parameters to the function start with `False` the check the code does is against `True` hence it will not the program will exit after first check itself.

{Note: A dry run of the code will print statements can help you get the logic right}